# I need to my query make it as multiple index how is it is possible

Tags: progress-4gl

```
FOR EACH customer no-lock where cs-id = "ABC" AND em-id = "123" AND  vehicle = YES:
    Display customer.  
END.

INDEX
 idx1  cs-id  em-id country state 
 idx2   cs-id vehicle
```

My query took only `idx2` it is not took multiple index if it will take both index performance will improve.

**Question :** how to make query multiple index.

**Note: where condition should be same**

Comment: I'm not a 4GL guru by any means, but if your progress version is 7 or later, I'd try something like `FOR EACH customer no-lock where (cs-id = "ABC" AND em-id = "123") AND (cs-id = "ABC" AND vehicle = YES):`

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21099) covers multiple index selection in Progress

In the arcticle they mention the following:

> When the selection criteria includes the use of AND, **more than one
>   index will be used when all the components of each index are involved
>   in equality matches**, and the indexes are not unique.

In your query you are not specifying country and state so I don't believe that a multiple index will kick in.

Progress does not use the amount of data in the for each to determine which index to use. I am going to assume that using cs-id, em-id returns less rows compared with the idx2 using the vehicle, so force progress to use the idx1 as follows

> FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK WHERE 
>                 customer.cs-id = "ABC" AND customer.em-id = "123" AND
>   customer.vehicle = YES
>          USE-INDEX idx1:
>          Display customer.      END.

Comment: Additionally - using multiple indexes is not a performance panacea.  You are almost always better off with a single multi-component index that matches your query criteria.  In this case that would be an index on cs-id, em-id and vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both indexes you have to use all index fields in your query so :

```
FOR EACH customer no-lock 
    where cs-id = "ABC" 
    AND em-id   = "123" 
    and country = "XX"
    and state   = "YY
    AND vehicle = YES:
    Display customer.  
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use both indexes, using the correct index is what is important. Using an index allows progress to return the least amount of data and since you are using cs_id & vehicle this will mean that index2 would in most cases be efficient.

If you have a very large db with a lot of records still in idx2 or you regularly have to find records based on the three fields you specified, then it might be worthwhile creating a 3rd index with all three fields.

idx3  cs-id  em-id vehicle

If you want to force OpenEdge to use multiple indexes and you are usign the AND operator then you must meet all of the following conditions:

- All matches are equality matches.
- All indexes are non-unique indexes.
- All components of an index are included.